# How do I create a static function to be used in two .c source files?

Tags: c, static

I don't want to put the static function definition in two source files(of the same module),

as that's duplicate.

Also I have to declare it as static, because I don't want other modules to use it.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Put the function header in a header file (.h).. can I suggest you find  a good C tutorial ?

Comment: Are you sure this won't cause duplicate?IMO it's going to create a definition for each compile unit.

Comment: No, it's going to declare it, but it's not going to define the symbol.

Comment: No, you keep the signature in the header, the linker will find it and link to it.  This is the way to do things if you're using it in separate files.

Comment: I want to share the static function ONLY for the two specific source files, this is what my question is for.

Comment: This is common when you try to modularize the source layout.

Comment: @new_perl the modularization features of C is very limited. keep that in mind. If you really need this, you put the function in a .h (or.c , or .whatever) file, and you #include that file only in the two source files you want it in. This will cause the code to be duplicated ofcourse, but there will be no linker errors as long as you declare the function static.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like mutually exclusive requirements; you want a single implementation of a function to be shared between two translation units, but you want to declare it `static` so that it isn't visible to other translation units.  Unfortunately, C doesn't offer that kind of granularity; a symbol is either visible to all other translation units or it isn't.

You can fake it by putting the function *definition* in a header file (declared static), and then `#include` it in the source files that need it:

```
#ifndef FUNC_H
#define FUNC_H

static void func() {...}

#endif
```

The thing is, each translation unit that includes this file will have a redundant implementation of the function.  That may or may not be a big deal for you.

Personally, I'd just declare the function normally in its own translation unit, create a header for it, only include the header in the files that need to call that function, and document that function should *only* be called from those files.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by two files of the same module, but the point of static function is that their scope is limited to file, so the best you can do is to `#include` one file into the other instead of linking them together. If I got your right...

Comment: You're confusing me. You can put static function with the definition into header file, in this case you'll have it defined in both. You can  include one file into another so that the function is available for both and make them compile in one invocation. That is - the files separation is only physical for whatever convenience it may provide (I wouldn't do it). Or you can make it non-static.

Answer (score 0):

If the function is short or simple, you might define it (giving also its body) in a header file as a *static inline* function, e.g.

`/* in header.h */`

`static inline int sum3(int a, int b, int c) { return a+b+c; }`

But you really should read a good book on programming in C.

Answer (score 0):

The primary purpose of the static keyword is to create an object that will exist throughout the duration of the program. But all objects declared at file scope ("global") behave in this way, no matter if they are static or not: they have *static storage duration*.

But it also means that the object cannot be accessed outside the scope it is declared. Functions are declared at file scope ("global") and therefore a static function will only be accessible from the very same file it is declared in. So it doesn't make sense to declare such a function inside a header.

What I *think* you are trying to do is this:

```
// function.h
void the_func (void);


// function.c
#include "function.h"

static void the_private_func (void);

void the_func (void)
{
  do_things();
  do_private_things();
}

static void the_private_func (void)
{
  ...
};


// some_caller.c
#include "function.h"

...
the_func();
```

At least this it what makes sense in an object-oriented design.